# Retrieve a list of all tables in the database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this database file under the usual databases folder and a bunch of tables inside it.

Please note that I don't want to retrieve under the command line. **I know I can use the ".tables" command.**

I want to retrieve a list of all tables in it, using code, so that I can execute some specific algorithms on each of them.

Also, I didn't find any questions with this problem on Android, so please forgive me if there is any. I was wondering if there is any function I can use under `DatabaseUtils`, but I didn't find any either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use

```
select name from sqlite_master where type = 'table'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just adding to the answer, I noticed that there are two columns with the same values for sqlite_master, at least on Android: name and tbl_name. I saw on Google something about them (tbl_name, particularly) being the same for tables, just being different (name) to other stuff. So I should be safe reading from tbl_name whenever I want to retrieve the table name, right?

Comment: No, you should stick to 'name'.

Comment: from https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html ...
For indices [...] name is the name of the index and tbl_name is the name of the table to which the index belongs.