# Intercept DB error "file is encrypted or is not a database"

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Because of I am trying to implement import/export data I want to test what happen if the imported file is not a sqlite database to manage the error.

In logcat I have the following:

```
03-22 15:02:39.957: E/SQLiteLog(20407): (26) file is encrypted or is not a database
03-22 15:02:39.978: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(20407): Corruption reported by sqlite on database: /data/data/com.crbin1.ltd/databases/dbltd
03-22 15:02:40.017: E/DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler(20407): deleting the database file: /data/data/com.crbin1.ltd/databases/dbltd
```

The application simply create a new empty db without error for user.

After db import I call the following code (DatabaseLTD is my SQliteOpenHelper class)

```
private void checkImportedDb() {
    try {
        DatabaseLTD dbltd = new DatabaseLTD(mCtx);
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbltd.getReadableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I am not able to intercept the "file is encrypted or is not a database" error. How can I catch the error to manage it?

Comment: I just noticed that you wrote "DatabaseLTD is my SQLiteDatabase class", but I see you use a getReadableDatabase() method (which is provided by SQLiteOpenHelper by default). Are you sure you didn't meant "DatabaseLTD is my SQliteOpenHelper subclass"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQLiteOpenHelper constructor:

```
public SQLiteOpenHelper (Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler)
```

requires an error handler argument "DatabaseErrorHandler".

> to be used when sqlite reports database corruption, or null to use the default error handler.

which might be what you are looking for.

**EDIT**: as crbin1 correctly pointed out, the constructor is API >= 11 only.

For API < 11 my (untested) suggestion would be to open the database and obtain a list of tables:

[Retrieve a list of all tables in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141435/retrieve-a-list-of-all-tables-in-the-database)

if the db you are supposed to load is bound to have at least one, you can either check the number or, even better, ensure that a specific table already exists.

If you'd like to be able to check empty DBs as well, as a last ditch effort you might try the SQLiteDatabase method:

```
public static SQLiteDatabase openDatabase (String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int flags)
```

I didn't checked but I *strongly suspect* that the documentation of this method is incorrect, as the information about the "flag" parameter is inconsistent, in particular the line:

> Open the database according to the flags OPEN_READWRITE OPEN_READONLY CREATE_IF_NECESSARY and/or NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS.

clashes with the presence of the "int flags" parameter:

> flags  to control database access mode

I know I'm a slacker and I should check this myself, but If that would be the case, you might try to pre-verify the database using openDatabase, with OPEN_READONLY and without CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, catch the exception (if any), and then go on with the "standard" SQLiteOpenHelper approach.

Comment: You are right DatabaseLTD is my SQLiteOpenHelper subclass, not SQLiteDatabase. That constructor required API 11, and for previous versions?